# Adding a using directive to a class programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-package

I am studying Visual Studio Extensibility.
This code from *MSDN* creates a new C# solution containing a project with a class:

```
EnvDTE.DTE dte =   this.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SDTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;
EnvDTE80.Solution2 solution = (EnvDTE80.Solution2)dte.Solution;
try {
    solution.Create(@"F:\Dev\Visual Studio 2013\Packages\Spikes\VSPNewSolution\Test\MySolution", "MySolution");

    string templatePath = solution.GetProjectTemplate("ConsoleApplication.zip", "CSharp");
    string projectPath = @"F:\Dev\Visual Studio 2013\Packages\Spikes\VSPNewSolution\\Test\MySolution\MyProject";

    /*
     * from MZTools site :
     * Once you have the template file name, you can add a project to the solution using the EnvDTE80.Solution.AddFromTemplate method.
     * Note: this method returns null (Nothing) rather than the EnvDTE.Project created, 
     * so you may need to locate the created project in the Solution.Projects collection. 
     * See PRB: Solution.AddXXX and ProjectItems.AddXXX methods return Nothing (null).
     */
    EnvDTE.Project project = solution.AddFromTemplate(templatePath, projectPath, "MyProject", false);

    EnvDTE.ProjectItem projectItem;
    String itemPath;

    // Point to the first project
    project = solution.Projects.Item(1); // try also "MyProject"

    VSLangProj.VSProject vsProject = (VSLangProj.VSProject)project.Object;
    vsProject.References.Add("NUnit.Framework");

    // Retrieve the path to the class template.
    itemPath = solution.GetProjectItemTemplate("Class.zip", "CSharp");

    //Create a new project item based on the template, in this case, a Class.
    projectItem = project.ProjectItems.AddFromTemplate(itemPath, "MyClass.cs");
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
}
```

I managed to add a reference to *MyProject* using *VSLangProj* .
So far, so good.
The resulting class is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyProject
{
    class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

What I did not found after a lot of googleing is a way to add a using directive 
in the class code ( *using NUnit.Framework;* in this case ).
The trivial way would be to write the line directly manipulating the class document.
Is there a way to do it programmatically using Visual Studio Extensibility ?

**UPDATE**

After some tries to get the *CodeClass* object for the created class,
I tried the code posted in [Finding a ProjectItem by type name via DTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549186/finding-a-projectitem-by-type-name-via-dte)
with little changes.
Here is the updated code :

```
EnvDTE.DTE dte = this.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SDTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;
EnvDTE80.Solution2 solution = (EnvDTE80.Solution2)dte.Solution;
try {

    string solutionPath = @"F:\Dev\Visual Studio 2013\Packages\Spikes\VSPNewSolution\Test\MySolution";
    solution.Create(solutionPath, "MySolution");

    string templatePath = solution.GetProjectTemplate("ConsoleApplication.zip", "CSharp");
    string projectPath = @"F:\Dev\Visual Studio 2013\Packages\Spikes\VSPNewSolution\\Test\MySolution\MyProject";

    EnvDTE.Project project = solution.AddFromTemplate(templatePath, projectPath, "MyProject", false);

    EnvDTE.ProjectItem projectItem;
    String itemPath;

    foreach (EnvDTE.Project p in solution.Projects) {
        if (p.Name == "MyProject") {
            project = p;
            break;
        }
    }

    VSLangProj.VSProject vsProject = (VSLangProj.VSProject)project.Object;
    vsProject.References.Add("NUnit.Framework");

    itemPath = solution.GetProjectItemTemplate("Class.zip", "CSharp");
    projectItem = project.ProjectItems.AddFromTemplate(itemPath, "MyClass.cs");

    // I decided to save both, just in case
    solution.SaveAs(solutionPath + @"\MySolution.sln");
    project.Save();

    EnvDTE.CodeClass codeClass = FindClass(project, "MyClass.cs");

    // Display the source code for the class (from MSDN).

    if (codeClass != null) {
        EnvDTE.TextPoint start = codeClass.GetStartPoint(EnvDTE.vsCMPart.vsCMPartWhole);
        EnvDTE.TextPoint finish = codeClass.GetEndPoint(EnvDTE.vsCMPart.vsCMPartWhole);
        string src = start.CreateEditPoint().GetText(finish);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(src, codeClass.FullName + "Source"); 
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
    }
}

private CodeClass FindClass(Project project, string className) {
    return FindClass(project.CodeModel.CodeElements, className);
}

private CodeClass FindClass(CodeElements elements, string className) {
    foreach (CodeElement element in elements) {
        if (element is CodeNamespace || element is CodeClass) {
            CodeClass c = element as CodeClass;
            if (c != null && c.Access == vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessPublic) {
                if (c.FullName == className)
                    return c;

                CodeClass subClass = FindClass(c.Members, className);
                if (subClass != null)
                    return subClass;
            }

            CodeNamespace ns = element as CodeNamespace;
            if (ns != null) {
                CodeClass cc = FindClass(ns.Members, className);
                if (cc != null)
                    return cc;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Well, it turns out that *FindClass* always returns null, because project.CodeModel.CodeElements.Count is zero. 
Duh ?

**UPDATE 2**
Well, please don't beat me.The original code had a surplus backslash in the *projectPath* variable.
This caused the project.CodeModel.CodeElements.Count to be zero.
Also, *FindClass* requires the class *FullName* without the extension and searches *public* classes only.
I corrected the code but still got *null* in return ( my own fault, I guess : I must have missed something ).
Anyway, *FindClass* searches the given class in **all** project CodeElements, including the classes in 
the project references.
This is an overkill in my case, since I am searching a class local to the project.
So I wrote a function that just does that.
Here it is :

```
public static CodeClass FindClassInProjectItems(Project project, string className) {
            CodeClass result = null;
            foreach (EnvDTE.ProjectItem pi in project.ProjectItems) {                
                if (pi.Name == className + ".cs") {
                    if (pi.FileCodeModel != null) {
                        foreach (EnvDTE.CodeElement ce in pi.FileCodeModel.CodeElements) {
                            if (ce is EnvDTE.CodeClass) {
                                result = ce as EnvDTE.CodeClass;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (ce is EnvDTE.CodeNamespace) {
                                CodeNamespace ns = ce as CodeNamespace;

                                if (ns.Name == project.Name) {
                                    foreach (CodeElement sce in ns.Members) {
                                        if (sce is CodeClass && sce.Name == className) {
                                            result = sce as CodeClass;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }                                    
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }        
            }
            return result;
        }
```

It works so I created a static *ClassFinder* class and added the function.
The next step was to retrieve the full class source code, including the using directives.
I found a sample on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/envdte.codeclass.getstartpoint(v=vs.110).aspx), this is the crucial code :

```
// Display the source code for the class.
TextPoint start = cls.GetStartPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartWhole);
TextPoint finish = cls.GetEndPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartWhole);
string src = start.CreateEditPoint().GetText(finish);
```

Actually, the first line throws an exception.
So I tried all the members of *vsCMPart* enum : most of them throw an exception, except :
*vsCMPart.vsCMPartBody*, *vsCMPart.vsCMPartHeader*, *vsCMPart.vsCMPartNavigate* and *vsCMPart.vsCMPartWholeWithAttributes*.
*vsCMPart.vsCMPartHeader* and *vsCMPart.vsCMPartWholeWithAttributes* return the same result ( at least in this case ),
while the others do not return the whole code.
To keep it short :

```
private void DisplayClassSource(CodeClass codeClass) {
    EnvDTE.TextPoint start = codeClass.GetStartPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartHeader);
    EnvDTE.TextPoint finish = codeClass.GetEndPoint();
    string source = start.CreateEditPoint().GetText(finish);        
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(source, codeClass.FullName + "Class source");
}   

private void DisplayNamespaceSource(CodeNamespace codeNamespace) {
    EnvDTE.TextPoint start = codeNamespace.GetStartPoint(EnvDTE.vsCMPart.vsCMPartWholeWithAttributes);
    EnvDTE.TextPoint finish = codeNamespace.GetEndPoint();
    string src = start.CreateEditPoint().GetText(finish);
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(src, codeNamespace.FullName + "Namespace source");
}
```

If we want the source code as it appears in the IDE, including the using directives,
we must use the classCode.ProjectItem object :

```
    private void DisplayClassFullSource(CodeClass codeClass) {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        foreach (CodeElement ce in codeClass.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel.CodeElements) {
            if (ce.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementImportStmt) {
                // this is a using directive
                // ce.Name throws an exception here !
                sb.AppendLine(GetImportCodeLines(ce));
            }
            else if (ce.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementNamespace) {
                sb.AppendLine();
                sb.AppendLine(GetNamespaceCodeLines(ce));
            }
        }

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(), codeClass.FullName + "class source");
    }

    private static string GetImportCodeLines(CodeElement ce) {
        TextPoint start = ce.GetStartPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartWholeWithAttributes);
        TextPoint finish = ce.GetEndPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartWholeWithAttributes);
        return start.CreateEditPoint().GetText(finish);
    }

    private string GetNamespaceCodeLines(CodeElement ce) {
        EnvDTE.TextPoint start = ce.GetStartPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartWholeWithAttributes);
        //EnvDTE.TextPoint finish = codeClass.GetEndPoint(EnvDTE.vsCMPart.vsCMPartWhole); // ERROR : the method or operation is not implemented
        EnvDTE.TextPoint finish = ce.GetEndPoint();
        return start.CreateEditPoint().GetText(finish);
    }
```

Now we are very near to the problem's solution. 
See my answer. 
(sorry if this looks like a novel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way as far as I can tell to add a using directive to a CodeClass.
The only way I found is this :
It certainly needs improving but it works.
This code assumes that all using directives are all in a row, at the top of the class code.
It will not work properly if a using directive is present within the namespace, for instance.
It adds the given directive just after the last found.
It does *not* check the code to determine if the directive is already present.

```
    private void AddUsingDirectiveToClass(CodeClass codeClass, string directive) {
        CodeElement lastUsingDirective = null;

        foreach (CodeElement ce in codeClass.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel.CodeElements) {
            if (ce.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementImportStmt) {
                // save it
                lastUsingDirective = ce;
            }
            else {
                if (lastUsingDirective != null) {
                    // insert given directive after the last one, on a new line
                    EditPoint insertPoint = lastUsingDirective.GetEndPoint().CreateEditPoint();
                    insertPoint.Insert("\r\nusing " + directive + ";");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So, the final working code is

```
        EnvDTE.DTE dte = this.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SDTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;
        EnvDTE80.Solution2 solution = (EnvDTE80.Solution2)dte.Solution;
        try {
            /*
             * NOTE while the MSDN sample states you must open an existing solution for the code to work,
             * it works also without opening a solution.
             */
            string solutionPath = @"F:\Dev\Visual Studio 2013\Packages\Spikes\VSPNewSolution\Test\MySolution";
            solution.Create(solutionPath, "MySolution");

            string templatePath = solution.GetProjectTemplate("ConsoleApplication.zip", "CSharp");
            string projectPath = solutionPath + @"\MyProject";

            /*
             * from MZTools site :
             * Once you have the template file name, you can add a project to the solution using the EnvDTE80.Solution.AddFromTemplate method.
             * Note: this method returns null (Nothing) rather than the EnvDTE.Project created, 
             * so you may need to locate the created project in the Solution.Projects collection. 
             * See PRB: Solution.AddXXX and ProjectItems.AddXXX methods return Nothing (null).
             */
            EnvDTE.Project project = solution.AddFromTemplate(templatePath, projectPath, "MyProject", false); 

            // the following code would do since there is only a single project
            //project = solution.Projects.Item(1); 

            // tried this :
            // project = solution.Projects.Item("MyProject"); 
            // but it throws an invalid argument exception

            // search project by name
            foreach (EnvDTE.Project p in solution.Projects) {
                if (p.Name == "MyProject") {
                    project = p;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // add a reference to NUnit
            VSLangProj.VSProject vsProject = (VSLangProj.VSProject)project.Object;
            vsProject.References.Add("NUnit.Framework");

            // Retrieve the path to the class template.
            string itemPath = solution.GetProjectItemTemplate("Class.zip", "CSharp");

            //Create a new project item based on the template, in this case, a Class.

            /*
             * Here we find the same problem as with solution.AddFromTemplate(...) ( see above )
             */
            EnvDTE.ProjectItem projectItem = project.ProjectItems.AddFromTemplate(itemPath, "MyClass.cs");

            solution.SaveAs(solutionPath + @"\MySolution.sln");                                
            project.Save();

            // retrieve the new class we just created
            EnvDTE.CodeClass codeClass = ClassFinder.FindClassInProjectItems(project, "MyClass");                               

            if (codeClass != null) {
                DisplayClassFullSource(codeClass);
                AddUsingDirectiveToClass(codeClass, "NUnit.Framework");
                project.Save();
                DisplayClassFullSource(codeClass);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
        }            
    }
```

**P.S.**
Before accepting this answer, I'll wait a while in case someone else posts a better solution.

**EDIT**
Time passed, no further posts on the subject. I marked this as the accepted answer.